# Sencha Touch 2 app doesn't show google map on Samsung Galaxy Ace

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, extjs, sencha-touch-2, google-maps-markers

I've written an app which shows current location on map.
The problem is that it works on Galaxy Tab 10.1, HTC Desire, Desire Z, Galaxy S
BUT when I use Samsung Galaxy Ace or emulator with Android 2.3.3 it doesn't work - t shows me just grey screen.

Code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.WhereAmI', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'whereAmI',

config: {
    layout: 'fit',
    scrollable: true,
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    style: 'text-align: center; background-color:white;',

    items: 
    [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Where am I?',
            items: [
                {
                    ui: 'back',
                    xtype: 'button',
                    id: 'back',
                    text: 'Back'
                }
            ]       
        },
        {
            xtype: 'mapview'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

mapview:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.MapView", {
    extend: "Ext.Map",
    xtype: 'mapview',
    config: {
        useCurrentLocation: true,
        mapOptions:{
            zoom: 14,
        },
        listeners: {
            maprender : function(comp, map){
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(this._geo.getLatitude(), this._geo.getLongitude()),
                    map: map
                });                 
            },
        }
    },
})
```

and of course in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

Is it possible to make it works?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Problem was in the device settings.

```
Settings -> Location and security -> My location -> Use wireless networks
```

on my device was unchecked. It works when it's checked.